# CosmosDb query nested data filtering by root fields

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've got a json structure as follows:

```
{
"id": "123",
"date": "2020-06-02",
"product": {
    "code": "A1",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "parents": [
        {
            "code": "P1",
            "name": "Parent 1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "code": "C1",
                    "name": "Child 1",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I need to return a flat structure eg.

```
date,       product.code, parents[].code, parents[].children[].code
----------  ------------  --------------  -------------------------
2020-06-02  A1            P1              C1
```

But filtering on the date field in the root of the json document.
Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you're handling the `parents[]` and `children[]` arrays. In your flat structure, it looks like you're assuming a single array element for each. Is that really the case? If so, just curious why you've chosen arrays. As for how you'd query the data, please edit to show what you've tried, where you're stuck, output issues, etc. Also, it would help if you clarified which API you're using.

Comment: Do you consider using code to process the received json and extract the corresponding value?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sql:

```
SELECT c.date,c.product.code,d.code AS parentCode,e.code AS childrenCode FROM c join d in c.product.parents join e in d.children
```

Here is the result:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-06-02",
        "code": "A1",
        "parentCode": "P1",
        "childrenCode": "C1"
    }
]
```

Hope this can help you.